# Spain-Issued Multiple Entry Schengen Visa - Can I go to Spain on the second trip rather than first?

Tags: schengen, spain, croatia

I am planning to go to Spain to celebrate the New Year, but before then, if my visa situation permits, I also plan to go to Croatia in November.

Due to me working abroad, I will only have time to apply for one visa.

The question is, if I state in the visa application to the Spanish Embassy that I am going to Croatia for 5 days in November in the first trip, then leave the Schengen area for a month and then go to Spain for 10 days during the New Year for the second trip, would it be reasonable to expect the Spanish Embassy to provide me with a multiple entry visa starting from November or is this just a pipe dream?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You can always ask, but you're likely to be disappointed.

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  Croatia is not in the Schengen area.

Comment: Croatia is not yet part of the Schengen area, so much of this is academic. Also, if you've not been to a Schengen country before then you're unlikely to get a multiple entry visa this time.

Comment: @CannonFodder Apologies, allow me to add further info. I have been in the Schengen areas a few times, and currently hold a 3-month multiple entry schengen visa to the Netherlands (unfortunately expiring in October)... Before that I held a 1-year multiple entry visa from France. I've never been to Croatia, but I believe you can enter using a Schengen visa (as well as a Croatia-issued visa of course).

Comment: If you went to the Spanish with a request to visit, say, Germany (instead of Croatia) and Spain, they'd simply refer you to the Germans. I imagine they'd do exactly the same with Croatia. The difference is that Croatia can't issue a Schengen visa. As phoog says, you can ask...

Answer (score 1):

I am very sure that I answered a similar question not very long ago, but I can't find it anymore. Perhaps it was deleted by the author.

You are right that you are allowed to enter Croatia if you hold a multiple entry Schengen visa. There are some restrictions, but not likely applicable in your case.

That does however not mean, that a Schengen state consulate will issue you a visa with the purpose of visiting Croatia. If you unveil your real travel plans in the visa application to the Spanish consulate, they will unlikely issue you a visa for the trip to Croatia.